TypeError: 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' object is not callable
Имя файла handlers20.py
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

from app.Keyboards import (main_kb, catalog_kb)
from app.database.Ruquests import ruquests20 as rq
router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Добро пожаловать в каталог недвижимости BiG.\n\n Что вас интересует?', reply_markup=main_kb.main)

@router.message(F.text == 'Каталог')
async def catalog(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Виберите интересующий вас тип недвижимости из списка ниже', reply_markup= await catalog_kb.catalog())

Ниже новый файл
Имя файла catalog_kb.py
from aiogram.types import (InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton)



catalog = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Квартиры', callback_data='apartament'), InlineKeyboardButton(text='Дома', callback_data='house')],
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Участки', callback_data='area'), InlineKeyboardButton(text='Коммерция', callback_data='commerce')]])

Ошибка в терминале:
  File "/Users/vladimirzitenev/Documents/BIG/app/handlers20.py", line 16, in catalog
    await message.answer('Виберите интересующий вас тип недвижимости из списка ниже', reply_markup=catalog_kb.catalog())
                                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'InlineKeyboardMarkup' object is not callable


Сделайте так reply_markup=catalog_kb.catalog вместо reply_markup= await catalog_kb.catalog()
